# QMenu* << QAction* -- Help Me Write A Global QMenu Insertion Operator

Tags: c++, qt

If for no other reason than for my own amusement, I wish to write a global insertion operator so I can use the fancy code:

```
aQMenu << aQAction1 << aQAction2 << aQAction2 << seperator << aQAction3;
```

Perhaps you hate the syntax, but I would at least like to try my hand at using it.  The problem is, that this is the first time I have tried to write insertion operator code, and I am stumped.  The code for inserting the enum "seperator" to the QMenu* is easy, and I have that working, but I thought this code would work for inserting a QAction* to a QMenu*:

```
// does not compile:  "must have an argument of class or enumerated type"
QMenu *operator<< (QMenu *menu, QAction *action)
{
        menu->addAction(action);
        return menu;
}
```

The compiler complains saying this function needs an argument of a class or enumerated type, which confounds me because the second parameter is of class type..  I have tried to rephrase this function using the ampersand, but I have not hit upon the way of writing it down properly.  I have looked a lot at web examples, and thought it is about time to just as the question here.

I know that some coders out there will complain about me deviating from standard Qt syntax, but I am having fun overloading the operator<< with other classes as well.  It just seems that the insertion operator works nicely here.  What can I say -- it makes me happy.

Comment: "the second parameter is of class type" is wrong - it's a pointer, and a pointer is a primitive value, not of class type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler complains because all the parameters are pointers. Using a reference for the menu parameter of the operator it would look like this:

```
QMenu& operator<< (QMenu &menu, QAction *action) {
    menu.addAction(action);
    return menu;
}
```

Now this operator should work on menu objects. If you want to use it with a pointer to a menu you need to dereference that pointer when applying the new `<<` operator:

```
QMenu *menu = new QMenu();
QAction *action1, *action2;
...
*menu << action1 << action2;
```

Comment: Can anyone recommend a *comprehensive* guide to operator overloading.  I have read a few trivial ones, but nuances such as what I am encountering are not discussed well at all.

Answer (score 0):

Everything works fine now.  I use the code

```
QMenu& operator<< (QMenu &menu, QAction *action) {
    menu.addAction(action);
    return menu;
}
```

so I can juggle my QMenu with the nice little syntax of

```
*mnuFile << actNewFile << actOpenFile << actCloseFile << seperator << actExit;
```

(another code snippet lets the insertion operator take my "seperator" argument).

Also, I read on these forums that Andrei Alexandrescu devotes quite a few pages on smart logger singletons in "Modern C++ Design".  I am still trying to grasp while my operator<< code

```
QMenu* operator<< (QMenu* obj, MyMenuInsertEnum val);
```

is valid (the first parameter is a pointer).  But this is not:

```
QMenu *operator<< (QMenu *menu, QAction *action);
```

And the problem is just the pointer as the first argument.  After I read the aforementioned book then I will append my findings here, providing I learn something new.